# How can I limit or specify imported data in React using mapping?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Making my first steps in React with a single-page-application, I want to import a static set of personal data such as:

```
   {
    id: '1',  
    link: 'john-doe',
    name: 'John Doe',
    title: 'Head of Business Development,
    bio: 'Advises major banks and health insurers on topics including strategy, risk management, and operations effectiveness'
  },

  {
    id: '2',  
    link: 'jane-doe',
    name: 'Jane Doe',
    title: 'Operations Director',
    bio: 'works with retail and consumer-goods companies to guide growth, commercial and operational transformations'},
```

And pass them into a component using the map function:

```
        {TeamData.map((item, index) => {
          return (
              <div>
                <h1 className="text-3xl xs:text-2xl md:text-3xl lg:text-5xl xl:text-6xl mb-5">{item.name}</h1>
                <p className="text-xl leading-10 uppercase mb-5 text-gray-700">{item.title}</p>
                <p className="text-xl leading-10 mb-5">{item.bio}</p>
                </div>     
          );
        })}
```

The component containing the mapping function is supposed to be placed on individual pages, each one for a specific team member. Running the mapping function above results in **every** data entry of *name, title and bio* from the data set being passed into the component, but I want to limit the import to a specific set, such as the only the set with the id '2'.

How can I limit or specify the data to be imported into the component?

Comment: you can use `Array.filter()` for getting specific data, or in general if you want to limit, you can call `Array.slice()`

Comment: Can you give me an example of how that function would look like limiting the import of the dataset with the id '1' ?

Comment: `TeamData.filter(item => item.id === '1').map(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{TeamData.slice(0, limit).map((item, index) => {
      return (
          <div>
            <h1 className="text-3xl xs:text-2xl md:text-3xl lg:text-5xl xl:text-6xl mb-5">{item.name}</h1>
            <p className="text-xl leading-10 uppercase mb-5 text-gray-700">{item.title}</p>
            <p className="text-xl leading-10 mb-5">{item.bio}</p>
            </div>     
      );
    })}
```

Comment: This throws a "'limit' is not defined  no-undef" error.

Comment: Limit is a number, like 5, .slice(0, 5)

Comment: Thanks for being specific! As far as I can see now, your answer perfectly solved my problem - just for a better understanding of the theory: the syntax of  

slice(First number, Last number)

sets the range upon which the limit is applied? .slice(3, 6) would import all data from ID 3 to ID 6 - correct?

Answer (score 0):

Make the component so it can take a specific ID based on the place where you use it (Or name). Then filter your data based on that ID (or name) and continue mapping like before.

```
export default function MyComponent({id}){
      TeamData.filter(team => team.id === id).map((item, index) => {
        return (
            <div>
              <h1 className="text-3xl xs:text-2xl md:text-3xl lg:text-5xl xl:text-6xl mb-5">{item.name}</h1>
              <p className="text-xl leading-10 uppercase mb-5 text-gray-700">{item.title}</p>
              <p className="text-xl leading-10 mb-5">{item.bio}</p>
              </div>     
        );
      })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your app set up you could use something like [react-router](https://reactrouter.com/) to switch between pages, or you could use state to identify which person from the list has been clicked on.

This example uses state.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Example({ data }) {

  // Add the data to the state
  const [state, setState] = useState(data);

  // Add a new state that captures the person id
  const [personId, setPersonId] = useState(null);

  // When a person's name is clicked on set the person id
  function handleClick(e) {
    setPersonId(Number(e.target.dataset.id));
  }

  // When the reset button is clicked go back to the list
  function reset() {
    setPersonId(null);
  }

  // If personId state is null print out all the names
  if (!personId) {
    return state.map(obj => {
        return (
          <div
            key={obj.id}
            data-id={obj.id}
            onClick={handleClick}
            className="name"
         >{obj.name}</div>
       );
    });
  }

  // Otherwise print out the person's details
  const person = state.find(obj => obj.id === personId);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{person.name}</div>
      <button className="reset" onClick={reset}>Reset</button>
    </div>
  );

};

const data = [{ id: 1, name: 'Bob' }, { id: 2, name: 'Sam' }, { id: 3, name: 'Claire' }];

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Example data={data} />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
.name:hover { background-color: #efefef; cursor: pointer; }
.reset { margin-top: 1em; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```